# Unable to clone Git repository - "Object function ... has no method 'hasMagic'"

Tags: ember-cli

I am trying to clone a Git repository, which contains an Ember-CLI project (https://github.com/tgfischer/StockMarketApp). When I do that, I get the following error:

```
tom@tom-fischer:~/Desktop/StockMarketApp$ ember server
version: 0.2.0-beta.1
Could not find watchman, falling back to NodeWatcher for file system events
Livereload server on port 35729
Serving on http://0.0.0.0:4200/
Object function glob(pattern, options, cb) {
  if (typeof options === "function") cb = options, options = {}
  if (!options) options = {}

  if (typeof options === "number") {
    deprecated()
    return
  }

  var g = new Glob(pattern, options, cb)
  return g.sync ? g.found : g
} has no method 'hasMagic'
TypeError: Object function glob(pattern, options, cb) {
  if (typeof options === "function") cb = options, options = {}
  if (!options) options = {}

  if (typeof options === "number") {
    deprecated()
    return
  }

  var g = new Glob(pattern, options, cb)
  return g.sync ? g.found : g
} has no method 'hasMagic'

    at rimraf (/home/tom/Desktop/StockMarketApp/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-caching-writer/node_modules/rimraf/rimraf.js:57:13)
    at lib$rsvp$node$$tryApply (/home/tom/Desktop/StockMarketApp/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-caching-writer/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1467:11)
    at lib$rsvp$node$$handleValueInput (/home/tom/Desktop/StockMarketApp/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-caching-writer/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1567:20)
    at fn (/home/tom/Desktop/StockMarketApp/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-caching-writer/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1555:18)
    at /home/tom/Desktop/StockMarketApp/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-caching-writer/index.js:100:14
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$tryCatch (/home/tom/Desktop/StockMarketApp/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/promise-map-series/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:489:16)
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$invokeCallback (/home/tom/Desktop/StockMarketApp/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/promise-map-series/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:501:17)
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$publish (/home/tom/Desktop/StockMarketApp/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/promise-map-series/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:472:11)
    at Object.lib$rsvp$asap$$flush [as _onImmediate] (/home/tom/Desktop/StockMarketApp/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/promise-map-series/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1290:9)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:330:15)
```

Here are the steps I am following:

```
git clone https://github.com/tgfischer/StockMarketApp
cd StockMarketApp
bower install
npm install
ember server
```

`ember server` runs the project, and generates the error above.

When I run the version of the project that is locally on my computer (The project that is pushing to this repository), it works correctly. I've tried uninstalling/reinstalling Bower, Ember-CLI, PhantomJS. I've also tried cloning this project on my Windows parition without success.

Does anyone know what might be going wrong? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Looks like a `glob@4.5.1` issue I just fixed it changing the `package.json`
to use a version that was working for me

Instead of `"glob": "^4.0.5"` use `"glob": "4.4.0"`

Then reinstall you packages

`npm cache clean
rm -rf node_modules
npm install`

(`ember-cli@0.2.0` works for me with the default glob version, you are using the `0.2.0-beta.1` maybe if you update ember-cli it will work)

Comment: This worked for me, except I needed to run 'npm cache clean' before re-installing because I was getting some errors otherwise.

Comment: Thank you @SeanK, I just updated it with your comment

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to this solution, which did work for me, there is now a recommended solution available on GitHub for Ember-cli:

https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/3486

Upgrading to Ember-cli 0.2.0 should fix the problem, but if that's not an option you can add `"rimraf": "2.2.8"` to your package.json and freeze glob at 4.0.5.

Answer (score 1):

Tried juan's answer but it didn't work in my case. This solution did though:

```
npm explore ember-cli -- npm i glob@latest -S
npm explore ember-cli -- npm i bower
```

Many thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/175117/thock for the help!